# Setting the correct z position of a child window

Tags: c++, winapi

I have an application that has a main window. I am writing a dll that is used by this application. I can retrieve the hwnd of this main window. What I want to do is add a child window that will behave as child element of the main window - basically be pinned to its topleft corner. I have created this child window like this form within my dll:

```
WNDCLASSEX wc;
wc.hInstance = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = "InjectedDLLWindowClass";
wc.lpfnWndProc = DLLWindowProc;
wc.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_BACKGROUND;
if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    return 0;

gHwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE , "InjectedDLLWindowClass", "InjectedDLLWindowClass", NULL, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 400, 300, widgetHWND, NULL, NULL, NULL);
SetWindowLong(gHwnd, GWL_STYLE, 0); // to remove all borders
```

I wanted to get the WM_SIZING and WM_MOVING messages in my child DLLWindowProc fuction and use SetWindowPos function to set the correct size and position for my child window. But since its the parent window that does the moving and resizind no mesages arrived. I tried to set a periodic timer that will update my child window size, position and window order but it only resulted in my window constantly becoming active and seizing control. So my question is - how do I pin the child window to parent window without access to parent window WinProc?

Comment: Subclass the parent window (assuming your window is on the same thread).

Comment: Unfortunately it is not. I have tried using MoveWindow instead of SetWindowPos. It works for setting correct size and position for my window without making it take control. However z order of windows is still an issue.

Comment: Make your window owned by the parent, then it will always be on top of it.

Comment: I have changed my window style to WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW and added     
 SetWindowLongPtr(gHwnd, GWLP_HWNDPARENT, (LONG_PTR)widgetHWND);

SetParent(gHwnd, widgetHWND);    
However parent window still appears on top of a child window whenever I focus on it

Comment: UPD: I have digged a bit further into this and discovered that my parent window was itself a child. With this in mind I was able to achieve desired result. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: @Gaxx For the benefit of future visitors to this page, I suggest you post your new, working code as an answer (you can answer your own question, might even get an upvote).